# Ordering in careers doesn't let me move first or last question

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The order of questions in my profile seems to be in a different order than I remember. I'm guessing it's in the reverse order of what what there previously.

Regardless, I attempted to reorder the list and found that I can't move the first or last question. The first question in the list will only let me move it further *up* (it's already at the top) and the last question will only let me move it further *down* (it's already at the bottom)

[image: Reordering questions] and [image]

Comment: The bug goes even deeper, looks like that even for the items that "works" the new order is not saved, and there is no "save" button.

Comment: The "remove" does work, so only the ordering is borked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason we were displaying the answers in reverse order. This meant that the answer at the top of the list was supposed to be the one at the bottom, so it only had a "move up" button and not a "move down" button.

I've just pushed a fix for this so we're now displaying answers in the correct order again, and re-ordering them works properly.